# Routing guard dependency injection

Tags: angular

lets say we have a moduleA and in it i have several child components which are protected by canActivate so my question here is should i add my canActivateRouting guard to the provider's of app.module.ts or moduleA.module.ts ? and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could provide the guard in either module but I would opt to provide it in the app.module.ts.  That way when you are defining your routes you only need to specify the guard once and all child routes in moduleA.module.ts are protected.

So your app.module routes would include this (note I'm also [lazy loading the routes](https://alligator.io/angular/lazy-loading/)):

```
...
{
  path: 'module-path',
  loadChildren: () => import('./path/to/module').then(m => m.MyModule),
  canActivate: [MyGuard]
},
...
```

and your moduleA.module child routes would like something like this:

```
...
{ path: 'a', component: MyAComponent },
{ path: 'b', component: MyBComponent },
{ path: 'b:id', component: MyBComponent }
...
```

Each of the child routes would then be protected by the guard.

Comment: ok that helped me out . but i got another thing so, i tried to use providedIn injector over to moduleA indead of using root.
now getting a circular dependency . 
thats cz i also have imported it in my moduleA.routing.ts. 
ever encountered ?
just stuck at that part . why?
although used your advice .  but not getting why not that way? with circular dependency.

Comment: If you're adding the guard at the app.module level like above you would not include it in your moduleA routing.  Only provide the guard once (in app.module.ts).